# Reading a set from file and changing to key dictionary

Tags: python

I have a file with following contents :

```
{ATG,TGG,TGC,GTG,GGC,GCA,GCG,CGT}
```

How can I transform it into a dictionary in following manner :

```
x={1:'ATG',2:'TGG',3:'TGC',4:'GTG',5:'GGC',6:'GCA',7:'GCG',8:'CGT'}
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, if you want to get a proper answer you need to update your question with the code that you have tried so far and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: But I have seen many questions answered in SO.I am not asking full code but just the function as I am unable to proceed with this.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is incomplete you need to update your question by information about your file format and your code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use one magic line:

```
dict(enumerate(a[1:-1].split(",")))
```

Assuming a contains string `{ATG,TGG,TGC,GTG,GGC,GCA,GCG,CGT}`

Now for how this works:

`a[1:-1]` strips the first and last characters (at index 0, and len(a))

`split(",")` creates a list of string, separating on the comma.

`enumerate` takes a list and zips it with an array of indices from 0 to len(a)-1

finally `dict()` returns a dictionary from a list of tuples(or lists) of size 2.

Comment: Awesome !! It worked.Thank you very much.I need to learn more about enumerate function :).Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

By reading the file into a list `l = ['ATG','TGG','TGC','GTG','GGC','GCA','GCG','CGT']`, you could loop over the contents of the list to populate your `dict`:

```
x = dict()
for i in range(len(l)):
    x[i] = l[i]
```

Then calling `x` returns the dictionary you want:

```
x={1:'ATG',2:'TGG',3:'TGC',4:'GTG',5:'GGC',6:'GCA',7:'GCG',8:'CGT'}
```